# GIDSignIn getting HasNoAuthInKeychain

Tags: ios, google-signin

I'm using GIDSignIn on iOS.  Usually it's working fine.

However, here's a scenario that isn't working.

1. The user picks the Google sign in option in our app.
2. Chrome starts, prompting the user for credentials.
3. Our app is killed by iOS for whatever reason.
4. Chrome/Google uses open url to restart our app.
5. GIDSignIn's HandleURL is called as expected, everything looks great.
6. Our app calls SignInSilently, which fails with HasNoAuthInKeychain.

Assuming that our app might be killed every time Chrome is called, is there a way to get the SignInSilently to work?

Instead of calling SignInSilently, we can call SignIn, however that just restarts the regular sign-in process, opening Chrome, ....

Also, if after the HasNoAuthInKeyChain error we simply restart the app manually, SignInSilently works fine.

Comment: Any update on this? `hasAuthInKeychain()` returns `true` once I do first sign in, but on next launch of the app `hasAuthInKeychain` returns `false`